# Efficient way to compute $n$ products of $n$ numbers

Tags: algorithms, products

Say I have a set of $n$ numbers ${a_1, ..., a_n}$. I want to compute $n$ products, where the $i$th product is defined as the product of all elements in the set, except $a_i$. For example, for $n=5$, I want to compute the five products
\begin{align}
 \quad a_2 \cdot a_3 \cdot a_4 \cdot a_5, \\
a_1 \quad \cdot a_3 \cdot a_4 \cdot a_5, \\
a_1 \cdot a_2 \quad \cdot a_4 \cdot a_5, \\
a_1 \cdot a_2 \cdot a_3 \quad \cdot a_5, \\
a_1 \cdot a_2 \cdot a_3 \cdot a_4 \quad. 
\end{align}
In a straightforward manner I can do this with $n \cdot (n-2)$ multiplications. However, I could reuse some partial multiplications that appear in the first equation, store them, and then reduce the number of multiplications in the second equation. My question is what is the most efficient way to do this? Thanks in Advance.

Comment: You want to avoid divisions? Make arrays of the initial and final products, $L = [1,\,a_1,\, a_1\cdot a_2,\,\ldots]$, and $R = [\ldots,\, a_{n-1}\cdot a_n,\, a_n,\,1]$, and for each row, mutliply the fitting elements of $L$ and $R$ to do it in $O(n)$ multiplications.

Comment: I forgot to add this. Divisions are not allowed. Thanks for pointing this out.